# MAX485 Burns after working for some time. RS485

Tags: microcontroller, rs485

I am using the circuit provided in the datasheet of MAX485. But is getting burnt after some time of working. I don't understand what is the problem. I also tried getting new ICs from a trusted supplier, but the problem still persists.

It is working fine for some time, after that some small amount of smoke is coming from it and its input side is getting latched to 5V.

I connected it with a PIC Microcontroller. Everything else in the circuit is working fine including ethernet communication using ENC28J60 IC.

[image]

Edit :

So I understand that I need to connect common ground for RS485.

But I need to connect with devices directly working on AC mains. It only provides 2 lines of RS485 (A and B). How can I communicate with these type of devices without causing these problems ?

[image]

Comment: First of all show the schematic. Are you connecting the ground line along with the differential pair between the two communicating parties?

Comment: Circuit uploaded above, kindly check it. It is  as per datasheet only.  I am not connecting ground.

Comment: This is not a schematic. Show how it is integrated on your board. And you *have to* connect the ground in case the two systems are isolated or having different grounds..

Comment: Sorry I don't have the schematic with me. But It is same as that only.  RE and DE pin are shorted and connected to the microcontroller DI and RO connected to UART pins. Everything is working on 5V. ...  And it is working also.. .. but after sometime the MAX485 IC is getting burnt.

Comment: Again, what are you connecting to what with this communication? Two systems have to share the common ground.

Comment: You are possibly exceeding maximum ratings somehow.. But without actual circuit schematic, we cannot figure it out...

Comment: Your schematic does not show how the chips are powered/wired. Not connecting ground? You need to be clear about this.

Comment: Sorry, as per my understanding MAX485 is a differential bus, it doesn't require common ground.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. RS485 **does** require a common ground.

Comment: Of course it does. What do you think isolated 485 drivers and receivers are used for?

Comment: Ok then it might be the problem. Then I should use isolated 485 driver. Can you please suggest me an IC for that ?

Comment: Most main IC vendors and their outlets make isolated 485 drivers but I do urge you to come clean on the full schematic that shows how you produce local power to slaves. This can be the next thing to go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it. It was causing basically due to three issues.

1. Not making common ground for RS485 nodes
2. External noises/transient voltages captured by RS485 bus
3. Not earthing if using Class 1 SMPS

For solving the second problem I have used TVS diode as described in the [TI application note](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla292a/slla292a.pdf).

Doing above measures solved my problem.

If you cannot make common ground for different RS485 nodes, you may use isolated RS485 drivers. It think we can also use a back to back diode connected across both grounds to ensure that there won't be any big potential differences between them.

Comment: You've isolated the RS485? Not left the gnd unconnected, right?

Comment: I didn't isolated...... In my application I made the ground common because isolated drivers or making it was adding extra cost which was undesirable.

Answer (score 3):

> as per my understanding MAX485 is a differential bus, it doesn't
>   require common ground

There's your problem. Here's the fix: -

[image]

I don't speak Norwegian but I do recognize ground continuity in this circuit: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand my mistake. Can you suggest me an isolated RS485 driver IC ?? I cannot use common ground in my project.

Comment: One of my device is a RS485 Thermostat which is directly working on AC mains... So I cannot provide a common ground there.

Comment: @LigoGeorge I am pretty sure you can. Do you have the interface pinout?

Comment: Hi, Please check the above updated post....

Comment: How I am supposed to connect with that thermostat ?

Comment: Technical details of the device (i.e. a data sheet) is required to work out the likely way to connect data to it. Proper technical details about how the 485 interface might connect to live or neutral is important to know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use optocouplers. You probably know it already, this thread is very old. Or use a transformer to have a floating power supply. Then you can connect both grounds.